# Chosen jQuery plugin - event is not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have searched all over and found how to trigger an event for the Chosen jQuery plugin.

I have downloaded their example files and added this javascript to the end of the file.

This code should display in the console log every time I change a value from the .chosen-select form or when I type a key, but none is working.

In the console I have this error:
**TypeError: $(...).on is not a function**
refering to this line of code: **$('.chosen-select').on('change', function(e) {**

```
       $('.chosen-select').on('change', function(e) {
        // triggers when whole value changed
        console.log("value changed");
      });



       $('.chosen-select').on('keyup', function(e) {
        // triggers when each key pressed
        console.log("key pressed");
      });
```

So I think the plugin is not loading correctly..

Why is it not working? How could I fix it?

Ty,
Razvan

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, look: http://jsfiddle.net/L3jKu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. It might works..

```
$('.chosen-select').change(function () {
     console.log("value changed");
     alert("value changed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.  See the revised jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NgLM5/

```
$('.chosen-select').change(function(e) {
  // triggers when whole value changed
  console.log("value changed");
});

$('.chosen-select').keyup(function(e) {
  // triggers when each key pressed
  console.log("key pressed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in the console means that `.on()` isn't a function, probably because `$('.chosen-select')` is `null`.

You should verify that the tag you try to match is in the page and that the selector match the correct tag/id/class/whatever.

Comment: <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="17" id="single-label-example">

Comment: That's the form, and as you can see, the class is the same as in the script.. So it should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's also depend upon how your jquery script is loading. Is your jquery.js is loaded before this function? If it does, then move this script block after your jquery link.

Comment: my script is exactly after the chosen jquery insert link.

Comment: It is better to post your full code. Also try to replace $ with jQuery.

Comment: You are listening event which is not